# Why does Live Server increase uncaught errors every time I press the go live button?

Tags: visual-studio, liveserver

I installed the live server extension in visual studio. I created a new folder and a new HTML file to see if the live server function workers. I press the go-live button, and it does not work. I tried to right-click and open with the live server. It still didn't work. The only thing I found was the live server runtime explaining that I had an uncaught error with the phrase "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open". Every time I press the go live button, the uncaught errors increased every time I press the button.
[ENONENT: no such file or directory, open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuwg2.png)
[Go live button does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mla1O.png)
Does this mean anything? And can I fix this? How can I make my live server work?

I tried to reinstall Live Server. I tried to change the settings of the live server and my visual studio. I may have made some mistakes but none of the changes I made worked.